# How to write a Saltstack state script, before update latest git repo, make sure the repo destination is cleanup?

Tags: git, salt-stack

At first I wrote a saltstack state script, make sure my local directory always as new as the latest git repo(Shadowsocks .etc), then compile the directory:

```
Clone Shadowsocks Github:
  git.latest:
    - name: https://github.com/madeye/shadowsocks-libev.git
    - target: /usr/share/shadowsocks/
    - require:
      - pkg: Install Shadowsocks Depend Pkgs
      - cmd: Revert All

Build Shadowsocks Command:
  cmd.run:
    - name: |
        ./configure
        make
        make install
    - cwd: /usr/share/shadowsocks/
    - require:
      - git: Clone Shadowsocks Github
```

Execute first time will be fine.

But if the repo new update then execute state again will fail-- there has local files in the directory, `git.latest` got conflict, need cleanup first.

So I add a revert state:

```
Revert All:
  cmd.run:
    - name: |
        git checkout .
    - cwd: /usr/share/shadowsocks/
    - onlyif: ls /usr/share/shadowsocks

Clone Shadowsocks Github:
  git.latest:
    - name: https://github.com/madeye/shadowsocks-libev.git
    - target: /usr/share/shadowsocks/
    - require:
      - pkg: Install Shadowsocks Depend Pkgs
      - cmd: Revert All

Build Shadowsocks Command:
  cmd.run:
    - name: |
        ./configure
        make
        make install
    - cwd: /usr/share/shadowsocks/
    - require:
      - git: Clone Shadowsocks Github
```

Then it works great, but when I `rm -rf` `/usr/share/shadowsocks` directory, the state script fail: `Comment: Desired working directory "/usr/share/shadowsocks/" is not available`

I address the problem is `- cwd: /usr/share/shadowsocks/`, but I use onlyif to make the state run when /usr/share/shadowsocks exists.

Is it a way to write the state flow as below?:

if /usr/share/shadowsocks exist:

`Revert All:` -> `Clone/Update Git Repo` -> `Build it`

else:

`Clone/Update Git Repo` -> `Build it`

How to make it simple?

I end up by use a ugly solution:

`Clone Git Repo`(if revert error) -> `Revert` -> `Update Git Repo` -> `Build`,
the Clone/Update part almost same except the requirement.

```
Revert All:
  cmd.run:
    - name: |
        git checkout .
    - cwd: /usr/share/shadowsocks/
    - onlyif: ls /usr/share/shadowsocks
    - onfail:
       - git: Clone Shadowsocks Github

Clone Shadowsocks Github:
  git.latest:
    - name: https://github.com/madeye/shadowsocks-libev.git
    - target: /usr/share/shadowsocks/
    - require:
      - pkg: Install Shadowsocks Depend Pkgs

Update Shadowsocks Github:
  git.latest:
    - name: https://github.com/madeye/shadowsocks-libev.git
    - target: /usr/share/shadowsocks/
    - require:
      - pkg: Install Shadowsocks Depend Pkgs
      - cmd: Revert All

Build Shadowsocks Command:
  cmd.run:
    - name: |
        ./configure
        make
        make install
    - cwd: /usr/share/shadowsocks/
    - require:
      - git: Update Shadowsocks Github
```

I think there is always better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved perfectly by **Daniel Jagszen** in the salt community:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/salt-users/8SQG9KNEu44

It's probably because of the "cwd" argument

```
Revert All:
  cmd.run:
    - name: |
        git checkout .
    - cwd: /usr/share/shadowsocks/
    - onlyif: ls /usr/share/shadowsocks
```

AFAIK the cwd takes place before the onlyif check. So

```
Revert All:
  cmd.run:
    - name: cd /usr/share/shadowsocks/ && git checkout .
    - onlyif: test -d /usr/share/shadowsocks
```

should work.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I dont get the point here, but I think my use case pretty similar. I have state which has the task to assure that all repositories are in the correct state, this means also that they are clean, and files created during a build must be removed.

It has not much to do with salt in general I guess, just reset your repo before you update it:

```
....
cd $APP_DIR;
git clean  -d  -fx ""
git checkout $BRANCH
git pull
...
```

This is part of shell script which represents my build. If your directory is already clean, your state will not fail. You can always clean it.

And you always can write stateful scripts / states and communicate back to salt:

```
echo ""
echo "changed=no comment='Build failed, reason: ...'"
exit 1;
```

Comment: Sorry not mention that the problem was solved perfectly by **Daniel Jagszent** in salt community https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/salt-users/8SQG9KNEu44